# Netty Increase ChannelBuffer Size

Tags: java, netty

Hello I have a Netty Server with a handler that should accept strings. It seems to only receive content up to 1024 bytes. How can i increase Buffer size. I have already tried

```
bootstrap.setOption("child.sendBufferSize", 1048576); 
bootstrap.setOption("child.receiveBufferSize", 1048576);
```

without success.

The handler is as below

```
public class TestHandler extends SimpleChannelHandler {


@Override
public void messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, MessageEvent e) {

    ChannelBuffer buf = (ChannelBuffer) e.getMessage();

    String response = "";

    if (buf.readable()) {

        response = buf.toString(CharsetUtil.UTF_8);
        System.out.println("CONTENT: " + response);
    }

    System.out.println(response);


}

@Override
public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ExceptionEvent e) {
    e.getCause().printStackTrace();

    Channel ch = e.getChannel();
    ch.close();
}
```

}

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Are you using UDP ? If so, packets will max out at 1024 bytes. This code comment is in the QOTM code sample:

> Allow packets as large as up to 1024 bytes (default is 768). You could
>   increase or decrease this value to avoid truncated packets or to
>   improve memory footprint respectively.
>
> Please also note that a large UDP packet might be truncated or dropped
>   by your router no matter how you configured this option. In UDP, a
>   packet is truncated or dropped if it is larger than a certain size,
>   depending on router configuration.  IPv4 routers truncate and IPv6
>   routers drop a large packet.  That's why it is safe to send small
>   packets in UDP.

If you are using TCP, you should add a frame decoder and a string decoder into your pipeline before yout handler; Something like this:

```
pipeline.addLast("frameDecoder", new DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder(80960, Delimiters.lineDelimiter()));
pipeline.addLast("stringDecoder", new StringDecoder(CharsetUtil.UTF_8));
pipeline.addLast("myHandler", new TestHandler());
```

Mind you, you will need to modify your test handler because the MessageEvent will actually contain your string.

```
@Override
public void messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, MessageEvent e) {
    String response = (String) e.getMessage();
    System.out.println(response);
}
```

Make sense ?

Comment: Thanks Nicholas. Now I notice that the last line is not printed.Why?

Comment: Good question. Can you put a full end-of-line delimiter at the end of the last line ?

Comment: Thanks Nicholas. It is possible to use my own delimeter. Brilliant!!! This is a MUST-READ tutorial by Nicholas. http://seeallhearall.blogspot.kr/2012/06/netty-tutorial-part-15-on-channel.html...  p.addLast("frameDecoder", new DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder(8192, ChannelBuffers.wrappedBuffer("</message>".getBytes())));

Comment: UDP packets do have a default max size of 768, but if you increased max size does not max out at 1024. the max size can be increase as detailed in the following post: [Why is Netty giving me only 768 Bytes from UDP messages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11525712/why-is-netty-giving-me-only-768-bytes-from-udp-messages)

Answer (score 5):

In version 4.0.10.Final for UDP Buffer size is set to 2048 bytes.

If You want to increase it set ChannelOptions as follows:

```
option(ChannelOption.SO_RCVBUF, int bytes)
```

and also

```
option(ChannelOption.RCVBUF_ALLOCATOR, new FixedRecvByteBufAllocator(int Bytes))
```

Comment: The location of this has changed slightly since 4.0.10, `channel().config().setOption( ChannelOption.SO_RCVBUF, numOfBytes );` Thanks, cheers.