# Buffering a Byte Array (From a DatagramPacket)

Tags: java, performance, buffer, bytebuffer, datagram

So after looking around for a suitable library, I've decided to make my own and here is part of it.

```
try {
    DatagramSocket serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(client_port);
    byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];
    byte[] finalData;
    while (true) {
        DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
        erverSocket.receive(receivePacket);
        if (this.address == receivePacket.getAddress() && this.server_port == receivePacket.getPort()) {
            ** handler.onMessage(receivePacket.getData()); **
        }
    }
} catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(PacketHandler.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
```

*This code is obviously ran asynchronously.*

The receiveData is set to 1024, which is terribly wasteful. It also means that anything bigger than 1024 gets split into two or more "Events" fired by the library.

I was wondering how it is possible to make a buffer, as I've gone completely blank. Essentially, you'd have to count the number of bytes somehow and push it into a new array.

So I'm basically asking for an efficient method, which doesn't have to include code.

Comment: you're looking for tcp?

Comment: @jtahlborn No. This is intentionally UDP.

Comment: Why are you testing the address and port? The test can never fail.

Comment: @EJP Well, what if a third party sends a random UDP packet to that IP and port to imitate the server?

Comment: If those are source addresses/ports you should use the `connect()` method.

Comment: @EJP Oh, I see. One question, do you *have* to use it to receive packets? The server part of this is supposed to receive packets from multiple and random clients.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that you need to use UDP for it?
Seems like you should change it to TCP impelementation. Do you want to use **netty** for it ? See [here](http://netty.io/).

1024 bytes it's normal safe value for UDP datagaram, making it bigger can bring issues with router. (See https://stackoverflow.com/a/13089776/3502543).

If you don't want to use netty, you should provide something similar to DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder.

**edited.**

Comment: Yeah, I considered Netty and Apache Mina and the former was too complicated and too full of features I didn't need. The latter didn't give much control.

Comment: See pretty simple example in the main netty development branch, https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/master/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/qotm

Comment: At least using netty would be simpler than write your own UDP server implementation.

Comment: I'm finding it quite easy with a custom library actually. Everything is so much simpler for me. This buffering thing is just a small issue.

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks for the information. I've worked out that my tile maps can hold up to 8100 tiles like this, so it'll be fine with 1024 but you've saved me a lot of debugging. :)