# Increase max request size of HTTP Post in Spring Boot 2 (WebFlux)

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, reactor-netty

I receive the `HTTP 413 Payload Too Large` in case of making POST request with 38Kb of JSON data in the request body. I use WebFlux, Spring Boot 2.0.5 and Netty.

Can anyone tell me how to increase maximum request size for WebFlux?

```
org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException: ClientResponse has erroneous status code: 413 Payload Too Large
at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.DefaultWebClient$DefaultResponseSpec.lambda$createResponseException$7(DefaultWebClient.java:463) ~[spring-webflux-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:100) ~[reactor-core-3.1.9.RELEASE.jar:3.1.9.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1083) ~[reactor-core-3.1.9.RELEASE.jar:3.1.9.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDefaultIfEmpty$DefaultIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxDefaultIfEmpty.java:100) ~[reactor-core-3.1.9.RELEASE.jar:3.1.9.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMapFuseable.java:138) ~[reactor-core-3.1.9.RELEASE.jar:3.1.9.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMapFuseable.java:138) ~[reactor-core-3.1.9.RELEASE.jar:3.1.9.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.onComplete(FluxFilterFuseable.java:151) ~[reactor-core-3.1.9.RELEASE.jar:3.1.9.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1085) ~[reactor-core-3.1.9.RELEASE.jar:3.1.9.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCollectList$MonoBufferAllSubscriber.onComplete(MonoCollectList.java:117) ~[reactor-core-3.1.9.RELEASE.jar:3.1.9.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:130) ~[reactor-core-3.1.9.RELEASE.jar:3.1.9.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:130) ~[reactor-core-3.1.9.RELEASE.jar:3.1.9.RELEASE]
at reactor.ipc.netty.channel.FluxReceive.terminateReceiver(FluxReceive.java:380) ~[reactor-netty-0.7.9.RELEASE.jar:0.7.9.RELEASE]
at reactor.ipc.netty.channel.FluxReceive.drainReceiver(FluxReceive.java:204) ~[reactor-netty-0.7.9.RELEASE.jar:0.7.9.RELEASE]
at reactor.ipc.netty.channel.FluxReceive.onInboundComplete(FluxReceive.java:345) ~[reactor-netty-0.7.9.RELEASE.jar:0.7.9.RELEASE]
at reactor.ipc.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.onInboundComplete(ChannelOperations.java:338) ~[reactor-netty-0.7.9.RELEASE.jar:0.7.9.RELEASE]
at reactor.ipc.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.onHandlerTerminate(ChannelOperations.java:404) ~[reactor-netty-0.7.9.RELEASE.jar:0.7.9.RELEASE]
at reactor.ipc.netty.http.client.HttpClientOperations.onInboundNext(HttpClientOperations.java:612) ~[reactor-netty-0.7.9.RELEASE.jar:0.7.9.RELEASE]
at reactor.ipc.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelRead(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:138) ~[reactor-netty-0.7.9.RELEASE.jar:0.7.9.RELEASE]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) ~[netty-transport-4.1.29.Final.jar:4.1.29.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) ~[netty-transport-4.1.29.Final.jar:4.1.29.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340) ~[netty-transport-4.1.29.Final.jar:4.1.29.Final]
at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102) ~[netty-codec-4.1.29.Final.jar:4.1.29.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) ~[netty-transport-4.1.29.Final.jar:4.1.29.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) ~[netty-transport-4.1.29.Final.jar:4.1.29.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340) ~[netty-transport-4.1.29.Final.jar:4.1.29.Final]
at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:438) ~[netty-transport-4.1.29.Final.jar:4.1.29.Final]
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:310) ~[netty-codec-4.1.29.Final.jar:4.1.29.Final]
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:284) ~[netty-codec-4.1.29.Final.jar:4.1.29.Final]
at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:253) ~[netty-transport-4.1.29.Final.jar:4.1.29.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) ~[netty-transport-4.1.29.Final.jar:4.1.29.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) ~[netty-transport-4.1.29.Final.jar:4.1.29.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340) ~[netty-transport-4.1.29.Final.jar:4.1.29.Final]
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1434) ~[netty-transport-4.1.29.Final.jar:4.1.29.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) ~[netty-transport-4.1.29.Final.jar:4.1.29.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) ~[netty-transport-4.1.29.Final.jar:4.1.29.Final]
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:965) ~[netty-transport-4.1.29.Final.jar:4.1.29.Final]
at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163) ~[netty-transport-4.1.29.Final.jar:4.1.29.Final]
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:628) ~[netty-transport-4.1.29.Final.jar:4.1.29.Final]
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysPlain(NioEventLoop.java:528) ~[netty-transport-4.1.29.Final.jar:4.1.29.Final]
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:482) ~[netty-transport-4.1.29.Final.jar:4.1.29.Final]
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:442) ~[netty-transport-4.1.29.Final.jar:4.1.29.Final]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:884) ~[netty-common-4.1.29.Final.jar:4.1.29.Final]
```

Comment: You try to upload a multipartFile ?

Comment: @TinyOS No. Request body contains big JSON. it is sent as "Content-type: application/json"

Comment: Here may is your answer: **[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13086564/netty-increase-channelbuffer-size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13086564/netty-increase-channelbuffer-size)**, please give it a try.